# upate a column based on multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have Data frame :

[image]

And i need the result like this:

[image]

I am not getting a idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach like this should work.

```
val groupedDF = df.withColumn("item",when(col("has_pencil").equalTo("true"),"Pencil").otherwise(when(col("has_pen").equalTo("true"),"Pen")))
.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set(co("item")).as("has_items"))

val res = df.join(groupedDF,Seq("id"))
```